# Array.from(..) inside prototype with eventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, event-listener

I have the following code:

```
Array.from(navigation_element).forEach( function(e, i){ 
    e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    })
});
```

its a common code for me to approach on click events and it works fine in all cases. But now I faced with issue that its not working inside constructor (with protoypes, don't know if its important information). Here is the full code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/WjGrwb). Its on `line 50`. Can anyone explain me why it happens.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing it's because you're trying to add an event listener to a dynamically added element?

Comment: yeah, I thought about that too, but, it works fine like here: https://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/PmbqWZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `element_create_2` your do this:

`target.innerHTML += ...`

this replaces all html nodes inside of the container, including the previously added navigations links with their click handlers.

Comment: damn perfect! You made my day! Thanks a lot.